# set span position before and after another span

Tags: html, css, css-float

There is a `span` well positionned (in %), and I have to set a text before and one other after it. The position is only defined for the `span`.

This is the span already positionned :

```
<span style="left: 50%;display:block;position:absolute;top:-20px;font-size:12px;">↓</span>
```

In fact, the ↓ is positioned just before a progressbar to indicate one value , so the 50% indicate the middle of the progressbar.

So to add the text, I tried to make that but it doesn't work :

```
<span style="display:inline;position:absolute;top:-20px;font-size:12px;">Before</span>
<span style="left: 50%;display:inline;position:absolute;top:-20px;font-size:12px;">↓</span>
<span style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;top:-20px;font-size:12px;">After</span>
```

The app is in multiple language so the text used "Before" and "After" can change so we cannot say ok, the "Before text" takes 10px so we will decal it...

The arrow has to stay exactly in place!

Thanks in advance to help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
you could try something of the sort, just try to style it as your choice
<style>
 #container{ width:300px; position:relative; height:30px;}
 label{float:left;}
 #1 { width:5%;}
 #2 {width:10%; position:absolute; left:50%;}
</style>

<div id="container">
<div>
<label id="1">befoure</label ><label id="2">arrow</label><label id="3">After</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your ask @Robert ! But the width is not set :-/ check this : http://jsfiddle.net/ZJ4zJ/